# TypeError: movie.directors is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So i want to render a list of directors in my page by maping then to a

tag i get the directors property from the movie object and i know that it is well written because i can log it and i see the array, the problem is when i try to check it for the length or map it the page crashes and tells me "TypeError: movie.directors is undefined "

```
 <div className="director">
              <h3>DIRECTOR{movie.directors.length > 1 ? "S" : ""}</h3>
              {movie.directors.map((director) => (
                <p key={director.credit_id}>{director.name}</p>
              ))}
            </div>
```

if i do this:

```
<h3>DIRECTOR{movie.directors ? "S" : ""}</h3>
```

and i coment out the maping the page renders fine i also notice that the page crashes and gives me the error.

The error happens only if i refresh the page example i change it from

```
<h3>DIRECTOR{movie.directors ? "S" : ""}</h3>
              {/* {movie.directors.map((director) => (
                <p key={director.credit_id}>{director.name}</p>
              ))} */}
```

to:

```
<h3>DIRECTOR{movie.directors.length > 1 ? "S" : ""}</h3>
              {movie.directors.map((director) => (
                <p key={director.credit_id}>{director.name}</p>
              ))}
```

and save the file with out refreshing the page it works fine and the way i want it to but if i refresh the page the the error happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because your initial state is empty object it doesnt have directors.

so you can make it something like:

```
const [movie, setMovie] = useState({
   directors: []
})
```

So directors is empty array initially

Answer (score 0):

One thing to add here is, it is now a good choice to add an `empty array` as an `initial state`.

**Reason**

- You are `fetching` movies and in the meantime, you want to show a `loader` as a symbol of loading, then instead of using another state variable `loading` to show this, you can simple have an if condition while returning that,

  return movies === null ?  :
- Moreover, if you do not have any item after fetching, the how could you indicate that there are no items in the list, as you already have taken the list as `empty array` instead of `null`.

---

**Solution**

It is suggested to use a `null check` all the time, like

```
{movie?.directors.map((director) => (
    <p key={director.credit_id}>{director.name}</p>
))}
```

or

```
{movie && movie.directors.map((director) => (
    <p key={director.credit_id}>{director.name}</p>
))}
```

or
to show `<Loader/>` while loading

```
{movie=== null ? <Loader/> : movie.directors.map((director) => (
    <p key={director.credit_id}>{director.name}</p>
))}
```

These all will only render content if present and prevent any `null` or `undefined` content rendering